# Factoring simple Markov network

Tags: probability, graphical-model

Let $X$ by the joint distribution of the random variables $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$. Let $(A \perp B) \mid (C, D)$ and $(C \perp D) \mid (A, B)$.

[image: Four Node Markov Network]

I understand that this distribution should factor over the four pairwise cliques.

$\Pr(X) = \frac{1}{Z}\phi_1(A,D)\phi_2(A,C)\phi_3(C,B)\phi_4(D,B)$

However, I'd like to see how, starting with $\Pr(X)$, we could factor the distribution into appropriate functions. I've been knocking my head against this most of the day, so any hints appreciated.

Comment: Using Hammersley-Clifford, I get $$Pr(X)\propto \phi_1(A,B) \phi_2(C|A,B) \phi_3(D|A,B)$$ but this does not use the first independence assumption...

Comment: We can say that  
  
$$\Pr(X) = \Pr(C \mid A,B)\Pr(D \mid A,B)\Pr(A,B)$$   
  
but none of these factors correspond to a clique.

Comment: why don't you post this to the discussion forum of the PGM (probabilistic graphical models) class offered at coursera?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the canonical parameterization from the proof of Hammersley-Clifford. Copying  notes from Samson Cheung, you define a factor for all subsets of G:
$$
f_s(X_s = x_s) = \prod_{z\subset s}P(X_z=x_z, Z_{G\backslash=0})^{-1^{|s|-|z|}}
$$

You can show that $\prod_{s\subset G}f_s(X_s) = P(X)$, because the exponent makes all the subsets $z$ of $s$ cancel out, except for when $z = X$. You can also show that $f_s(X_s) = 1$ if $s$ is not a clique.

For your four node network, assuming Bernoulli RV, you take a default assignment like $(0,0,0,0)$. So, $f_{\{\}} = P(0, 0, 0, 0)$. Then, for example, $f_{\{A\}}(1) = \frac{P(1, 0, 0, 0)}{P(0,0,0,0)} $ and $f_{\{A, B\}}(1, 1) = P(1, 1, 0, 0)\frac{1}{P(1,0,0,0)}\frac{1}{P(0,1,0,0)}P(0,0,0,0) $.

Unfortunately, it's not as simple as comparing the factorization from the chain rule to the parameterization you want :-)